# Is sys.maxint safe to use?

Tags: python

As far as I know, in java Integer.MAX_VALUE is always equal to 2^31-1.
But it seems that in python the value of sys.maxint depends on the system you are on and the version of python. Is this correct? If I want to get the number 2147483647 is pow(2,31) -1 the only safe way?

Comment: What do you mean by "safe"? If you're on a system where `sys.maxint` is smaller than that value, then `pow(2,31)-1` will be a long (since, by definition, that value _cannot_ be stored as an integer on that particular system). Is that what you want?

Comment: Safe to use for what? Actually in python integers are automatically promoted to a type with unlimted size (long), i.e. `10 * 100` gives you Googol.

Comment: @myaut In fact, it won't let you call it as it raises a `MemoryError`

Comment: There's actually two different issues there. First, `range(sys.maxsize)` is asking for a list that must at least 4x as much virtual memory as your system can actually have, so of course that raises a `MemoryError`. But also, `long` values can't be used as indexes, so `xrange(sys.maxsize+1)` doesn't work in 2.x; in 3.x, `range` doesn't care about indexes, so `range(sys.maxsize+1)` is fine (but `spam[sys.maxsize+1]` _is_ still an error).

Comment: Also, please don't do this: `for i in xrange(sys.maxsize): print i,`

Comment: @Zizouz212: How about `timeit.timeit('for i in xrange(sys.maxsize): print i,))`? :)

Comment: Or that too. :) I'm sure people who don't close the window until execution stops will sure have a very happy time...

Comment: I think the part the OP either is actually asking about, or doesn't get but needs to, is this: Java defines its `Integer` type to be 32 bits. Python 2.x leaves it up to each implementation; the CPython implementation leaves it up to the C compiler (a Python `int` holds a C `long`), and the C compiler is going to give you a 64-bit int on most 64-bit platforms other than Windows. Hence, the maximum `Integer` and the maximum `int` aren't the same.

Comment: Guys, please stop. My example was only to show how absurd is OPs question (asking for safety without context). But actually using iterator over `xrange(sys.maxint)` is useful to generate sequence of ids

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sys.maxint` is safe to use as the maximum value of an `int`. If you want `2**31-1` regardless of what size `int` is, use `2**31-1` (and be aware that this will give you a `long` if it equals `sys.maxint`, since `2**31` will overflow, so call `int` on it if you need it as an `int` for some reason).

Comment: This is not true in Python 3.0+, where there is no such type as `long`. (It's also not true in Python 2.2-, where an `int` doesn't always get automatically promoted to `long`, but that's less likely to be relevant in 2015…)

Comment: On my computer: `sys.maxsize = 9223372036854775807`, while the Java maxsize is `2147483647`.

Comment: Oh, wait a sec, in 3.x, `sys.maxint` is just going to be an `AttributeError`, so… never mind. :)